# How to get specific row from a table with "group by" and "order by"

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table like below:

| tmp_id | product_availability (0 and 1) | is_available (0 and 1) | stock_count (integer) | product_id (integer) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 |

I need to get first available product for each `product_id`.
Available products MUST check `product_availability` first, then `is_available` and last check `stock_count`. (A product is available when `product_availability` is `1`, then `is_available` is `1` and in in stock with at least one product `1`.)

I want to show available products first, if there is no available product, it doesn't matter which product to show (first product is OK in unavailable situation).

*(In above example I need to get product with `tmp_id` of `2` first.)*

**Question:**
My question is how to write the **MYSQL** query to achieve my needs?

I can get my products in the wanted order with below command, but I don't know what to do next to get first existing product with `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT
    pa.*
FROM
    `product_advanced` AS `pa`
ORDER BY
    `pa`.`product_availability` DESC,
    `pa`.`is_available` DESC,
    `pa`.`stock_count` DESC
```

**NOTE:** Of course this is just a simple presentation of what I have, actual code is more complicated and have multiple joins and other things.

Comment: [MySql top 1 row in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `row_number()` to return Returns a unique row number for each row within a partition

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY product_availability DESC, is_available DESC, stock_count DESC) AS rn
  FROM product_advanced
)
SELECT tmp_id, product_availability, is_available, stock_count, product_id  
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Actually it works! But I have another question, is it any performance issue with it? because I have at least 5k rows and it grows too.

Comment: Another thing, if I want to change my driver from mysql to another sql driver, is it work? or any global solution for all sql langs?

Comment: It is working on most of databases, concerning the performance you probably need to add some indexes